# como meter un JSON en un un Spinner?

Tags: android, json, spinner

Traigo mi json desde un php y lo paso como `string` a mi activity class via `onPostExecute` desde `AsyncTask`:

```
public String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String type = params[0];

  String registro_url = "http://10.0.2.2/spinner2.php";
            String json = "";
            String result = "";
            try {

                URL url = new URL(registro_url);
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                http.setRequestMethod("POST");

                http.setDoInput(true);
                InputStream IS =http.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS,"iso-8859-1"));
                String Line;
                while((Line=BR.readLine())!=null){

                    json +=Line;

                }
                BR.close();
                IS.close();
                http.disconnect();
                result=json.toString();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result; }
        return null;    }
```

Eso me devuelve esto:

```
{"Preguntas":[{"Pregunta":"Tangananica o Tanganana?"},{"Pregunta":"Que le pasa a Lupita?"},{"Pregunta":"que sera lo que quiere el negro?"}]}
```

Luego tengo esto en mi class donde está el spinner

```
public class Seleccionpregunta extends AppCompatActivity {

    static Spinner sp;
    static TextView tv;
    ArrayList<String> outputDataList  = new ArrayList<String>();

    Context ctx;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seleccionpregunta);
        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.questionSpinner);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        MyTask BW = new MyTask(this);
        String type = "spinnerq";
        try {
            String taskResultx = new MyTask(this).execute(type).get();
            tv.setText(taskResultx);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}}
```

Necesito meter eso en un JSON pero no encuentro nada.

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero define un archivo llamado `OnPreguntasResponse` que sera la que recibirá los datos convertidos en `JSONObject` para poder acceder a los elementos del json:

```
public interface OnPreguntasResponse
{
  void onResponse(JSONObject response);
}
```

Modifica tu clase MyTask para que el constructor reciba ademas del contexto, la interfaz:

```
private OnPreguntasResponse mResponseCallback; 
public MyTask(Context context, OnPreguntasResponse responseCallback)
{
  //...

  mResponseCallback = responseCallback;
}
```

Ahora, sobre escribe el metodo `onPostExecuted` de tu clase MyTask que se ejecuta cuando metodo  `doInBackground` termina de ejecutarse. En este metodo ejecutas el callback y le enviaremos la instancia del método `JSONObject`:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecuted(string jsonResponse)
{
   mResponseCallback.response(new JSONObject(jsonResponse));
}
```

Entonces ahora cuando ejecutas MyTask, en constructor le envias la instancia del callback de esta manera:

```
new MyTask(this, new OnRespuestasResponse(){
  public void response(JSONObject response)
  {
     //...
  }
});
```

Ahora, dentro del metodo response hay que acceder los elementos del array. Para eso hay que acceder la propiedad `Preguntas` que retorna un `JSONArray`, y luego por cada pregunta, obtener la propiedad `Pregunta`. Entonces con un array de string(`string[]`) le asignamos cada pregunta al array luego utilizado el `ArrayAdapter` para que llene el `Spinner`:

```
new MyTask(this, new OnRespuestasResponse(){

  public void response(JSONObject response)
  {
    try{

         JSONArray preguntasJA = response.getJSONArray("Preguntas");

         String[] preguntas = new String[preguntasJA.length()];

         for(int i = 0; i < preguntasJA.length(); i++)
         {
            preguntas[i] = preguntas.getJSONObject(i).getString("Pregunta");
         }
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, preguntas);
         sp.setAdapter(adapter);
     }catch(Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

  }
});
```